# Node package priority, global vs local

Tags: javascript, angular, npm

I've noticed that I have Angular 2 installed globally, and I don't know when I might have done that, or if that's the way it's supposed to be. It doesn't seem like that would be necessary if it's defined in every project.

It makes me wonder what side effects that have if I had different versions locally and globally. Which one takes priority? What's the best way to remove all of the Angular packages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Globally installed NPM packages really only impact your command-line environment. Things like `pm2` or `sequelize` insert `bin/` stubs into the `PATH` to make your life easier.

In order to `require` something it needs to be present in `package.json` as well as properly installed.

Comment: Thanks. So then it is correct to have all the Angular packages installed globally?

Comment: It's not necessary, but it is often more convenient. You get to use (for example) `script` instead of `$(npm bin)/script`.